# Error in mysql "max_allowed_packet" VPS godaddy

Tags: mysql, virtualhost, vps, godaddy, moodle

I am getting error

"**Serious session error detected.
Please notify administrator, this problem is most probably caused by small value in max_allowed_packet MySQL setting.** "

This error generally comes after every 20-25 minutes and when it comes , it logs out the user and then logs in again, starts again and then after sometime the same issue occurs again.

I tried changing max_allowed_packet setting but getting error "access denied; You need SUPER privilege for this operation'.
I even tried SET SESSION too but error  "SESSION variable 'max_allowed_packet' is read-only. Use SET GLOBAL to assign the value"

I have hosted the website on godaddy VPS centos and access it via putty or cpanel.
Website is made in moodle 2.0.3 i.e. php.

My developers use to fix this but warned will occur when server restart. As godaddy ppl say move to dedicated and then i can do but as I don't have any money so can't at present.
I trying to find how developers used to do for temporary fix that is until server restart.

Comment: I have searched on net and tried most of the methods like set max_allowed_packet size...
But can't see if the effect has taken place as I m unaware of the location of file where the changes will take place.

Comment: Do you have root access to mysql server if yes try 'set global max_allowed_packet_size = SOMEVALUE' .

Comment: Sidenote: this is why documentation, change management, separation of development and operations duties, and incident tracking are important...

Comment: If this is a "VPS" You are the administrator.

Answer (score -1):

if you do not change it in the my.cnf file, Login to Mysql and run below command the value will reset when the server restarts, even if you set it globally.

```
  SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;
```

Comment: I already told giving error "access denied;super user privileges required"

Comment: @user2298854 Please hit the contact us link below to recover your password for your original account, and have your two accounts merged together.

Comment: Unless it has already been overridden to a very low value, this is not the way to fix the problem.